# Is it Possible to Add Multiple Frameworks to Xcode Project at Once?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, parse-platform

I feel like there should be an easy way to do this but can't find it. Whenever I use the Parse.com framework for an iOS project, I have to add at least 10 different frameworks, and as far as I can tell I can only add 1 at a time through the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` options in Xcode.

Any faster way to do this, besides creating a template project?

More specifically, the issue is that if I pick a framework, then search for another and hold CMD to select multiple, searching erases all previously selected frameworks (so I have to just scroll through the list).

Answer (score 2):

Searching (as you discovered) kills the current selection. You can cmd-click to select multiple, but only if you don't use search. It's annoying as hell.

Similar to the "add file to project" dialog that forces you to click the checkbox for every single target manually (no "select all targets").

One of those annoying parts of Xcode that apple hasn't prioritized as having enough user impact to fix (since most people add one framework, or just have one or two targets for the other example).